# Mdx error creating a calculated script member

Tags: mdx

I have an mdx script which I took from the browser but edited it a little and created a script in calculations but it's wrong?

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[RTY]
AS 
'SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Person ID Count] } ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Order Date Time Base].[Month Number Of Year].&[1], [Order Date Time Base].[Month Number Of Year].&[2], [Order Date Time Base].[Month Number Of Year].&[3] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Order Date Time Base].[Calendar Year].&[2015] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Scv Cube])) WHERE ( [Order Date Time Base].[Calendar Year].&[2015], [Order Date Time Base].[Month Number Of Year].CurrentMember)'
SELECT
{[Measures].[Person ID Count]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Scv Cube]
```

Whats wrong with this? I am very new to mdx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT` is not allowed in the `WITH` clause

Looks like you have a sub select - this goes in the `FROM` clause. I have commented out the currentmember near the end of the script as I am unsure of what happens if this is included in a `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT
  {[Measures].[Person ID Count]} ON COLUMNS
FROM 
(
   SELECT 
     NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Person ID Count] } ON COLUMNS 
   FROM 
   ( 
     SELECT 
       ( 
         { 
           [Order Date Time Base].[Month Number Of Year].&[1]
         , [Order Date Time Base].[Month Number Of Year].&[2]
         , [Order Date Time Base].[Month Number Of Year].&[3] 
         }   
       ) ON COLUMNS 
     FROM 
       ( 
         SELECT 
          ( { [Order Date Time Base].[Calendar Year].&[2015] } ) ON COLUMNS 
         FROM [Scv Cube]
       )
   ) 
   WHERE 
   ( 
       [Order Date Time Base].[Calendar Year].&[2015]
     //, [Order Date Time Base].[Month Number Of Year].CurrentMember
   )
);
```

What is the final goal of this script? Do you just want the total for `[Person ID Count]` in the first three months of 2015? If so this should help...

```
SELECT
  NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Person ID Count] } ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Scv Cube]
WHERE 
( 
   [Order Date Time Base].[Calendar Year].&[2015],
   { 
       [Order Date Time Base].[Month Number Of Year].&[1]
     , [Order Date Time Base].[Month Number Of Year].&[2]
     , [Order Date Time Base].[Month Number Of Year].&[3] 
    } 
);
```

Comment: i am trying to use that select statement in the new script command but it throws the error: `Parser: The script contains the statement, which is not allowed` when I try to process it

Comment: hey, im trying something else instead, not sure if thats the right thing to do, `COUNT(NONEMPTY([Measures].[Person ID Count],[Order Date Time Base].[Calendar Year].&[2016]))` so what I want from this is the count of personID on the year 2016 only.

Comment: this is wrong `NONEMPTY([Measures].[Person ID Count]...` the first argument of NonEmpty is a set - but you have used a measure (which will equate to 1 every time)

Comment: right ok. i am totally confused about this now. I will re phrase this cause maybe i havent explained it properly. I have a personIDCount which i have  got from the sales table (for my purposes). The slicing is done on the orderdate on the calendar year to be 2016/2015 (whichever i need) i want that to be expressed in a calculation. To get the personCount in @year year

Comment: `With Member Test As 
SUM([Measures].[Person ID Count])
SELECT NON EMPTY
{ Test } ON COLUMNS from
(Select ([Order Date Time Base].[Calendar Year].&[2015])on columns 
from [Scv Cube])` is this wrong? calculations allowed it when swapping from form view and script view but processing the cube throws an error

Comment: @faiz that small snippet in your comment looks valid i.e that it will run. Why do you insist on using sub-selects - why not get rid of that inner query and move the 2015 member into the outer query's `where` clause? The logic of Test looks a little odd as well .... I don't think I have ever needed to just SUM(<someMeasure>) - why not just put `[Person ID Count]` straight onto rows?

Comment: yes I ended up finding out its a single tuple so I changed it and it now works, but ran into another issue so will post a question on that to get opinions on how I can go about it

Comment: hey can u have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345256/count-of-ids-that-exists-in-both-calculated-members please. im very confused now with mdx

Comment: @Faiz did my answer help or can I delete this post?